# Object located in the main thread is not initialized by another thread

Tags: java

I put together a class of an client app that should connect to a socket and it should automatically retrieve a `DefaultTreeModel` from the server or a simple String object as a test. The issue is that inside the main `RemoteNetworking` class the `DefaultTreeModel` or the String are successfully received but if I try to get them using `getClientTreeModel()` or `verifiFromOutside` i'm getting only null objects. Can you please help me understand this behavior? I'll place the code bellow.

```
package Networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class RemoteNetworking extends Thread{

    private volatile Socket remoteSocket;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;
    private Thread currentThread;
    private volatile ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private volatile ObjectInputStream ois;
    private volatile DefaultTreeModel treeModel = null;

    private String IP;
    private int port;
    private static volatile String test;

    public RemoteNetworking(String IP, int port) {
         this.IP = IP;
         this.port = port;
    }


    public void connect() {
        try {
            SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(IP, port);
            remoteSocket = new Socket();
            remoteSocket.connect(socketAddress);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void setReceivedTreeModel(DefaultTreeModel receivedTreeModel) {
        this.treeModel = receivedTreeModel;
    }

    public synchronized void disconnect() {
        try {

            //oos.writeObject("Disconnect");
            oos.flush();
            //oos.close();
            isRunning = false;
            remoteSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized DefaultTreeModel getClientTreeModel() {
        return treeModel;
    }

    public synchronized void verifyFromOutside() {
            System.out.println(test);   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        connect();

        synchronized(this) {
            this.currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }

        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(remoteSocket.getInputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(remoteSocket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("DataTree");
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while(isRunning) {

            try { 
                   Object object = (Object)ois.readObject();

                    /*if(object instanceof DefaultTreeModel) {
                        //this received object is not null
                        setReceivedTreeModel((DefaultTreeModel)object);
                        if(treeModel==null) {
                            System.out.println("Null object in RemoteNetworking");
                        }
                        verifyFromOutside();
                    }*/

                   if(object instanceof String) {

                           this.test = (String)object;
                           System.out.println(test);       
                   }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. You have to show us both the client side AND the server side on how you send and receive the data.

Comment: Maybe [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) is more appropriate. It uses sockets to transfer objects from one JVM to another.

Comment: Hey guys. I solved the issue eventually. I just hat to initialize the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream.